# DSX PySpark writing data to dashDB with Custom JDBC dialect

Tags: pyspark, ibm-cloud, dashdb, pixiedust

In IBM Bluemix I have created a `DSX PySpark notebook`, with `Python 2.6` and `Spark 2.0`. I am using `IBM dashDB` as my data storage. I can authenticate and read tables successfully but when I try to write back to a new table I was getting this exact same issue as described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771799/spark-jdbc-to-dashdb-db2-with-clob-errors/40781925?noredirect=1#comment70717863_40781925) .

To fix this it was [suggested](https://apsportal.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/55e7fe57-c002-4180-bfa3-83fc6466a875/view?access_token=1792df00fbbcf6df08f73bec0055b34e988d323eea59aafc6cd12d2a4ea86ed0) to register a new custom dashDB JDBC dialect using a Scala bridge with the `pixiedust` library, but when I reach that stage in my Notebook I keep getting the following error:

```
pixiedustRunner.scala:13: error: type BeanProperty is not a member of package reflect
    @scala.reflect.BeanProperty
```

The scala bridge code in PySpark from the 2nd link:

```
%%scala cl=dialect global=true
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, BooleanType, DataType}

object dashDBCustomDialect extends JdbcDialect {
    override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:db2")
    override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = dt match {
            case StringType => Option(JdbcType("VARCHAR(" + maxStringColumnLength + ")", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR))
            case BooleanType => Option(JdbcType("CHAR(1)", java.sql.Types.CHAR))
            case _ => None
    }
}
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(dashDBCustomDialect)
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in PixieDust due to api changes for BeanProperty which moved from scala.reflect package in Scala 2.10 to scala.beans package with Scala 2.11.
A fix will be provided shortly but in the meantime, you can workaround this error by using Spark 1.6 which uses Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 1):

FYI. We are also working on updating DSX directly with the JDBC dialect fix for dashDB so that you won't have to do it as part of your notebook anymore. The fix will go out shortly. So stay tuned.